# Why header string is required for cout?

Tags: c++, string

Why in the below code without  including "string"  header I can declare string variable.
But compiler complains  only for cout, when I try to print the string.

What information "string" header consists of ?

```
  #include <iostream>
//#include "string"

int main () 
{
    std::string str="SomeWorld";

    std::cout<<str<<std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Because the header defining `std::basic_string` is most likely (indirectly) included by `<iostream>` (`std::string` is a typedef based on `std::basic_string<char>`). The overload for `operator<<` for `std::cout` however is only defined in `<string>`.

Comment: In Visual C++'s case, `<iostream>` includes the implementation-defined `<xstring>` header, which defines `basic_string` itself, but like you say, it doesn't define the `operator<<`.

Answer (score 2):

It's not required for `std::cout`, it's required for `std::string`.

Comment: ++. without including "string" header I can declare std::string variable. compiler is allowing to do that.

Comment: @user - It is allowed for one C++ header to include any other header. You cannot rely on this though, because it varies from one compiler to another. You should always include the headers you need.

Comment: @user430294: You always need a header that is documented to contain the type. Everything else is an implementation stuff, and not something you can rely on.

Comment: @Bo: note that in this case, `<iostream>` hasn't included another *header*, it has included "half a header" - `std::string` is there but `operator<<(std::ostream &, const std::string &)` isn't.

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking, anything could happen unless you include *all* the correct headers. There is no mandatory inclusion of one standard header into any other. So to be portable and correct, you have to say this:

```
#include <string>    // for `std::string`
#include <ostream>   // for `std::ostream &` in `operator<<`
#include <iostream>  // for std::cout

int main() {
  std::string str = "hello world";
  std::cout << str << std::endl;
}
```

In any real implementation you can almost always get away with omitting some of the headers (e.g. `ostream` would probably have been included in `iostream`), but the above is the standard-compliant way.

Answer (score 0):

The `<string>` header includes the definition of the `string` class (note: `#include "string"` means to include the `string` file in the current directory, so you should use angle brackets instead of `"` for system includes.)

However, `iostream` already includes `string`, (for example, to declare the `operator<<` that works for `std::string`) so this is why you don't need to include it in this case.

In any case, it is a good practice to include the headers you just need. This makes your code more portable, and more explicit in case you copy that code into another context, say, that don't include `iostream` as a previous include. Also, note that it is never specified that, for example, including `iostream` will make `std::string` available, so strictly speaking, you have to include `string` to use `std::string`.

Answer (score -2):

Because `<string>` is included in `<iostream>`. That is why the compiler is not complaning.

Comment: The questioner reports that the compiler *does* complain.

Comment: I think voting once was enough.